# Search by Image url Google

Tags: rest, api, search, google-api

I'm trying to search by image using Google Api, but its only search by image as a string  I mean it search for the image url  not the image itself

like this one

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCxJUGIb_tevRKD-Kxxi57OM1f6dbRLwf4&cx=010407088344546736418:onjj7gscy2g&q=http://i.imgur.com/n4BhXEC.jpg

I want to find same images even if the name and the url is different!

Is it possible ? since they have this feature for free like this one

> www.google.co.in/searchbyimage

Can I do it using API ?

Comment: Answer to the similar question: stackoverflow.com/a/60892228/1291371

Answer (score 0):

I never used google apis but there is one called vision api it is provided by GoogleCloud and you can use it to recognize images, I think that is what you want.